# CSS shrink image to fit caption

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is it possible to shrink the image to fit the caption using only CSS as in my mockup below?

My mockup [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/tadaz/pen/zYmvXmj)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure figcaption {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250">
    <figcaption>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Ideally, I would like to achieve using `TailWindCSS v2`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by 'fit the caption'? You have a container with fixed width and height - at what point do you want the image to shrink, say, so as to leave 'some' room for the caption if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You can try CSS grid like below:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%; /* take the height of container */
  display: grid; /* a grid layout */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto; /* two rows where the first one fill the space */
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0; /* the image won't increase the height of the grid */
  min-height: 100%; /* fill all the remaining space */
}

figure figcaption {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/250x250">
    <figcaption>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```